# Dumping/saving the list of Running apps in Kitkat 4.4.4

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-4, application-manager

Mobile phone : Galaxy S4 (T-mobile SGH-M919) running Android 4.4.4, 
               2GB RAM out of which 520MB is reported as free (as of NOW), 
               16 GB memory out of which 805 MB is reported as free - memory condition may have been different before 1 week as reported below.

I have searched the net and could not find a solution. My problem started couple of months ago on my 4 yr old galaxy S4.  It started random reboots with a message that will be something similar to "SIM card can not be detected. RESTART" and this was starting to occur almost everyday. Searching the net for this, i found various answers and clues as to why this could be happening. I removed the SD card that i had started using about 4 months ago, and the random reboots still continued. I was about to buy another phone, but thought i would try one last trick by closing unwanted apps (since heat generated by too many processes was indicated as a possible culprit, in one of the threads i saw earlier).

So, one week ago, i went into "Settings ->Application Manager" and hit the "STOP" on few apps that i randomly chose.  In 4 years, this is the first time i have attempted this, since i am not familiar with Android, and my phone was working fine for my purposes (of simple call & text). To my surprise, the phone has not rebooted in 1 week now. One of the reasons quoted in a forum about "SIM card not detected problem" was that the phone was overheating.  Coincidentally, the weather turned really cold in my area for past 1 week.  Now, i am not sure if the reason for the good behavior of my phone is weather or the stopping of some apps. I do not give much credit to the weather theory.  So, currently, i want to narrow down the culprit that is causing the random reboots. I have taken a screenshot of  the apps that show up in  "Settings->App Manager-> Turned OFF applications tab".

I have also taken screen shot of all "currently running apps & cached processes" right now.  I can compare these photos to the set of apps that would show up after i do an intentional reboot of this mobile (during which phone will go back to the condition as it existed more than a week ago).  I expect the "SIM card not detected->Restart"  message to show up again randomly,  once i reboot this mobile.

Question is ---- Is there a way to dump/save the list of apps/processes that are cached/running currently into a text file ? I am not Android savvy and want a simple user friendly solution.  Finally, if anyone here has a clue about why my phone has started random reboots in past 2 months, i would like to hear your theories.  (BTW, i think i was on android version 4.4.2 and once i did a manual upgrade of software, by going into settings.  So, i am pretty sure i upgraded to 4.4.4 sometime within the past 2 months.  Not sure if the upgrade could be causing problems because i changed quite a few things in my phone in past 2 months, during an international travel. This included new version of OS, installation of few apps that were useful in my travel,  installation of a new SD card slot  which was previously empty).  Thanks much for reading my entire story :-)

Answer (score 0):

Found  the answer to my problem.  I have rebooted the phone, and the apps that i "turned off"  stay "turned off"  and hence, i do not have the SIM card not detected->ReStart  issue anymore. Not sure if this was caused by one of the apps i turned off, or it is because i am pretty close to occupying  all of the 16GB i have on my phone with only 0.7gb free now in the phone.  Unlikely, since my RAM shows only about 1.2 out of the 2GB is being used.  I am surprised no one here could answer this question in 6  days.